# Client call to EJB error: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

Calling my EJB from class Main:

```
MyService myService = (MyService) ctx.lookup(MyService.class.getName());
```

Gives error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at com.ejb.calculator.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

How can I call my EJB?

Tried two different JNDI calls:

```
JNDI_NAME = "java:global/ejb/MyService";
MyService myService = (MyService) ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
```

and

```
MyService myService = (MyService) ctx.lookup(MyService.class.getName());
```

Code:

[Source link](https://bitbucket.org/powder366/ejb/src/master/)

```
https://bitbucket.org/powder366/ejb/src/master/
```

Glassfish commands:

```
asadmin start-domain --verbose
asadmin stop-domain --verbose 
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf
mvn package
asadmin deploy ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Note:

My test cases works with the embedded container, but I can't call my external running container.

Used versions are Java8, EJB3.0, Glassfish5.0.1, Java EE8.0.1

**Update1:**
Added log during deplyoment container-deploy-log.txt. See git remote.

**Update2:**
Pushed the working changes to git remote.

**Update3:**
Pushed MDB example to git remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to access your EJB from an external client, you need to declare a remote view.

As your EJB only has the `@Local` annotation, it only offers a local view. You should add the `@Remote` annotation.

```
@Local
@Remote
@Stateless
public class MyService implements IMyService {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

The global JNDI name is formed by:

```
java:global/[EAR module]/[EJB module]/[EJB name]
```

in your case, as there is no EAR, would be:

```
java:global/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MyService
```

This test should work:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
IMyService myService = (IMyService) ctx.lookup("java:global/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/MyService");
Assert.assertEquals(myService.getMessage(), "Hello!");
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to add the glassfish client libraries to the classpath to run the Main class.

I originally tested it with a JUnit test, it worked for me because the project already declared a `test` dependency on `glassfish-embeded-all` that includes the glassfish client. But IntelliJ doesn't add `test` libraries when running a Main class.

You could either change the scope of `glassfish-embeded-all` to `runtime` or add a new dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.appclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same error, the JNDI is correct what you said, gives this as output in the log while deploying. Running Main class nothing is shown in the container log. Probably never reach the container. Same error as described in question above... changes in git at remote. Also added log file container-deploy-log.txt

Comment: Are you runing the test class from another project?

Comment: This is the Main class im starting within IntelliJ https://bitbucket.org/powder366/ejb/src/master/src/main/java/com/ejb/first/Main.java, my Glassfish is running standalone on my same computer mac (outside IntelliJ). Deploying with: asadmin deploy ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar on Unix command line.

Comment: Ok. Didn't see that class, and was looking in the test/ dir. I will add the missing bits to the answer

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you release the bounty please? ;)

Comment: Ohh sure, did not realize I have to click one extra...ok now?